# How to output in Python

Tags: python-2.7, output

I cannot output in python

I have tried using the output statement-doesn't work, I cannot find a solution in the python documentation other than the print statement-but I do not want to print the "output" on a piece of paper.

```
kilometers = 5.5
conv_fac = 0.621371    

miles = kilometers * conv_fac
output('%0.3f kilometers is equal to %0.3f miles' %(kilometers,miles))
```

I want the code to output the correct answer in the Python shell but it does not work

Comment: First of all, `print` does not **print** the output on a piece of paper. Just use `print`, it writes to **standard output**, which is your `shell`.

Answer (score 1):

`print` "prints" to the standard output, I believe that's what you're looking for:

```
print('%0.3f kilometers is equal to %0.3f miles' %(kilometers, miles))
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the print() function to output data to the standard output device (screen).

```
kilometers = 5.5
conv_fac = 0.621371    

miles = kilometers * conv_fac
print('%0.3f kilometers is equal to %0.3f miles' %(kilometers,miles))
```